# is admin on facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I looked around and could not find anything to do this (well it was not obvious or semi-obvious)

So say i have a facebook application that offers a service that people will pay for during use.  The average user can come on and "Subscribe" to it, while the admin of those pages can perform an activity that will cost them money (make me money).

I do not want hacking attempts or anything to hurt our product.  So, how can i verify that someone is an admin using the PHP SDK.

What we are currently doing is storing the $_POST["signed_request"] in $_SESSION's data and working with that.  Either the $_POST or $_SESSION is not safe 100% (firesheep).

Is there any way to verify this? graph api?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first things first. To retrieve the `signed_request` and check if the user is an admin you would use something like:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if ($signed_request['page']) { // Loaded in a page tab
    if ($signed_request['page']['admin']) {
        // Current user is admin
    } else {
        // Normal user
    }
} else { // Canvas view

}
```

Now I'm not sure what do you mean by:

> What we are currently doing is storing the $_POST["signed_request"] in
>   $_SESSION's data and working with that.

Because if you are using the PHP-SDK then you don't need to worry about *storing* the `signed_request` in the session since the SDK will handle it for you.

Now for the last part:

> Either the $_POST or $_SESSION is not safe 100% (firesheep).

That's not true, the `signed_request` is *useless* without your app secret key to decode it. So even if someone was able to obtain it, it won't compromise your application. Read more about `signed_request`s [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).

Comment: Not true.  Fire sheep they steal the session information, and they pass in a signed request that says here is my app, and yes i am an admin... though they are not.

Comment: And i said "So, how can i verify that someone is an admin using the PHP SDK."  I think that it is possible to get that information, i just cannot find the commands for pages and what i require to find out if the current user is an admin for page x

Comment: @Michael, are you saving the "*decoded*" `signed_request` in the session?! because without your app secret key **they** can't pass a valid `signed_request` for you!

Comment: So say i have the "encoded" signed_request and i store it in $_SESSION["my_brand"]["signed_request"].  Some other dude (The hacker) knows that this client is using my program.  He firesheeps it, sets his $_SESSION data and now boom.  He looks like the admin. . .

Comment: PLEASE read the code above and the link I posted again. the *admin* info is only available **inside** the `signed_request` so if this is encoded the hacker **won't be able to alter it** because once this is done it will destroy the `signed_request` and the PHP-SDK will reject it.

Comment: Ok... so you still do not understand what i am saying...  So.  I have a signed request.  I want to use the PHP SDK to get the same information but from the php sdk because it is guaranteed to be from facebook (i believe) than from $_POST or $_SESSION data.  My question was IS there more reliable way than just relying on those...  The thing is some nefarious user could take the session information and pass that in the $_POST/$_SESSION and gain admin privileges...

Comment: Now that's a different question. The best way to prevent this is by using HTTPS (SSL certificate) which is a requirement by October.